# How to change hovers?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to change the **font size** and **color** of the `a` when I hover over `p`. It is not working. Probably there is a simple solution, but I am struggling with this for a few hours.

If anyone has not too complicated links related to this topic I also would be happy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      p:hover div nav a {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 22px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <p>Ceramics</p>
        <a href="">One</a>
        <a href="">Two</a>
        <a href="">Three</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector `p:hover div nav a` is incorrect. This would refer to an `<a/>` within a `<nav/>` within a `<div/>` within a `<p/>` that is being hovered. You can fix this with the change I made below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      nav p { /*selects all hovered <p/> within a <nav/>*/
        color: blue;
        font-size: 22px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <p>Ceramics</p>
        <a href="">One</a>
        <a href="">Two</a>
        <a href="">Three</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually want, that the font is getting bigger if you hover over p Ceramics.

Comment: @BenSreRsf please edit your question to make it very clear what functionality you want

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i get the simple solution for you .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
       
        
        p:hover + .hv {
        
        color: blue;
        font-size: 22px;
        
        }
        
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <p>Ceramics</p>
        <div class="hv">
        <a  href="">One</a>
        <a  href="">Two</a>
        <a  href="">Three</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great :) do you know what I should change, when I also want that it stays big, when I hover over the a ?

Comment: kidnly rate my post

Comment: Thank you for your help also in the other comment. Unfortunately there comes a message, that I can not rate, because I need more reputation

Answer (score 0):

Hi there ok so if i might get you . you want to get

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
       
        
        .hv a:hover{
        
        color: blue;
        font-size: 22px;
        
        }
        
        
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <p>Ceramics</p>
        <div class="hv">
        <a  href="">One</a>
        <a  href="">Two</a>
        <a  href="">Three</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:
`p:hover, a:hover {color: blue;font-size: 22px;}`